# Apply Converter to Displayed Item of ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, devexpress-wpf

I'm trying to apply a converter to the Displayed Item of the ComboBoxEdit

When I only use the ComboBoxEdit.ItemTemplate it works, but only for the Items inside the Combobox, not for the selected. As soon as i apply the DisplayTemplate it crashes with the error Can not Convert object of type "DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.EditGridCellData" to "System.Enum".

```
<dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding SampleList}">
        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Name"
                            FieldName="Name"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Beschreibung"
                            FieldName="Description"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Kategorie"
                            FieldName="Category">

                <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <dxe:ComboBoxEdit ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.CategoryList, ElementName=LicenseContainerRoot}"
                                          IsTextEditable="False"
                                          Name="PART_Editor">
                            <dxe:ComboBoxEdit.DisplayTemplate>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource EnumDescriptionConverter}}" />
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </dxe:ComboBoxEdit.DisplayTemplate>
                            <dxe:ComboBoxEdit.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource EnumDescriptionConverter}}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </dxe:ComboBoxEdit.ItemTemplate>
                        </dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
            </dxg:GridColumn>
        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
    </dxg:GridControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the available data context, where your converter is being invoked, is an EditGridCellData instance. Is the enum you are looking for inside the DataObject property, of the EditGridCellData?

If you have the source for EnumDescriptionConverter, you can put a debugger breakpoint on EnumDescriptionConverter.Convert (and determine what data type is being passed).